# I cant connect to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb

I tried to connect with 
`*mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.mi3o1.mongodb.net/test" --username cristian*` in the shell.
 
But instead, it looks like it's trying to connect with: 
`*mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb*`
I am getting the error

```
*Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1      
bash: mongodb+srv://cluster0.mi3o1.mongodb.net/test: No such file or directory*
```

I have created the cluster, database access with admin role user cristian, whitelisted both my IP and all IPs `0.0.0.0/0`, created a new database, loaded sample databases, opened ports `27015`,`27016`,`27017` and tested on portquiz.net.
I added a PRTSCN.
Please help!

[terminal prtscn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkrh9.png)

Comment: You didn't do the whitelist correctly or yourclusters are broken.

Comment: Thank you for your response, can you be more specific, please? i have whitelisted my ip and wait about 10 mins, i have tried with 0.0.0.0/0  (includes your current IP address). no succes. How could 2 clusters to be broken and what can i do to repair?

Comment: Your question includes no error messages. There is nothing to offer feedback on.

Comment: I didnt get an error message, can i log the error somehow?

Comment: If you have no error message, how do you know there is a problem in the first place?

Comment: Because i’m not propted fir a password and in the shell when i type show dbs after i’m connecting to atlas, it shows the local DB not the one from the cluster(test). In the printscrn i attach, after i press ctrl+C i get bash: mongodb:.... no such file or directory.

Comment: Question is missing complete input and complete results.

Comment: Can you please tell me what am i missing in the question?

Comment: Something like https://gist.github.com/p-mongo/14729236ad958cfe84dde756e32d2892. You see the command I ran and the complete output.

Comment: i've added a prtscn in the question now. thank you!

Comment: You have some kind of a shell/system problem. Either your bash is broken or whatever environment it's installed in is misparsing arguments.

Comment: Do you have any recomandation? reinstaling Mongo? ...this is my .bash_profile: alias mongod="/c/Program\ files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongod.exe"
alias mongo="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongo.exe

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much D. SM for your help, it looks like it was a problem with my .bash_profile. When i did the copy and paste for the 2 paths i dont know why the terminal writed the last " on another row and got some spaces between. I rewrited the 2 rows with no space like this:

alias mongod="/c/Program\ files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongod.exe"
alias mongo="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongo.exe"

and it worked.